# how to know imac crash reason

Tags: imac

last day i put my mac on the whole night for downloading xcode.however today i noticed that it is shutdown in the morning.i used the "last" command to know when it was shutdown.it is showing time 11:00am and a word crash besides.how can i know the reason for this crash.is there any tool or utility to know the reason.is there any log of it stored in mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Mac OS X's *Console* (found in */Applications/Utilities*) to monitor your system logs by filtering their contents.
Check first *system.log* and *console.log*. Logs display their information in reverse chronological order,  scroll down to reach content around 11:00am.